# OAuth and OpenId Connect Tokens clarification

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I did some solid research (IMHO) about OAuth and OpenId Connect. But I am still not completely sure about what and how to protect each token against. Let's put refresh token aside for a while and let's focus on ID token and Access token. From the security point of view, both must be treated the same. They must not leak public hence use only with HTTPS and avoid storage with unprotected read/usage at a client. From this, I assume that I can use only httpOnly cookies (XSS, CRFS protection, library leak) to store the token in case of a simple website (The server side is the issuer of JWT). Is it OK to store access token (directly or wrapped in ID token as a claim) in the cookie (I do not think about the size of token vs session id) or I should store it as server-side hence use classical session solution in case of a simple website?
In the case of SPA <-> API (<-> API...) I should/must use the Bearer token solution?

I think that I understand it right but want to be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be using access tokens straight from the frontend app, by making some AJAX calls to APIs, then you can't keep the access token in a httpOnly cookie. Your scripts will need to have access to it. You can keep the tokens in memory, if you a Single Page Application. The tokens will be useable for as long as the user does not refresh the page. After refresh you can perform silent logins to get new tokens from the backend.

If you have a simple website, and don't perform any calls to APIs directly from frontend I would stick to plain old sessions. You don't get any additional value from using access tokens over sessions in such a case.

> In the case of SPA <-> API (<-> API...) I should/must use the Bearer token solution?

Not sure what you're asking here. If you mean that in case of communication between an SPA and API you have to use an access token in the Authorization header instead of sending a cookie, then yes you're right. If you're asking whether you are bound to use bearer tokens, then no - there is something called sender-constrained tokens, which means that an access token is tied to the client it was issued to.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should store the tokens in the backend and perhaps use a simple session cookies against between the client and backend.

Some services (like ASP.NET Core) will by default store the tokens as a cookie. To protect the cookie they will encrypt it before sending it to the browser. So this means that even if the cookie is stolen, it can't be decrypted and hence the tokens are safe.

Yes, the cookie size will be pretty big but ASP.NET Core solves this by breaking up large cookies into chunks of 4 Kb. If you use HTTP/2 with its header compression, large cookies will not impact the transfer time.